# VBA: Find column header and reformat (date) values in columns

Tags: excel, date-format, vba

I have VBA code to perform some actions on data in excel file and then convert all that data into semi-colon separated CSV/text file (code below).

Now, all I want is to add VBA code in the existing macro to find a column header (say,  "Application date") and then convert all the dates into YYYY-MM-DD format.  The original values in this column don't have a fixed date format.

```
Public Sub ExportToCsvFile(FName As String, _
    Sep As String, SelectionOnly As Boolean, _
    AppendDataOnExistingFile As Boolean)

Dim WholeLine As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstCol As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
FNum = FreeFile

If SelectionOnly = True Then
    With Selection
        FirstRow = .Cells(1).Row
        FirstCol = .Cells(1).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
Else
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        FirstRow = .Cells(1).Row
        FirstCol = .Cells(1).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
End If

If AppendDataOnExistingFile = True Then
    Open FName For Append Access Write As #FNum
Else
    Open FName For Output Access Write As #FNum
End If

For RowNdx = FirstRow To LastRow
    WholeLine = ""
    For ColNdx = FirstCol To LastCol
        If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
            CellValue = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
        Else
           CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
           CellValue = Replace(Replace(CellValue, Chr(150), Chr(45)), Chr(151), Chr(45))
           CellValue = Replace(Replace(CellValue, Chr(60), Chr(60) & Chr(32)), Chr(10), "<br />")
           CellValue = Chr(34) & Replace(CellValue, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)
        End If
        WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
    Next ColNdx
    WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))
    Print #FNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #FNum

End Sub

Sub ExportToSemiColonCsv()
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim Sep As String
    FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=vbNullString, FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")
    If FileName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ExportToCsvFile FName:=CStr(FileName), Sep:=";", _
       SelectionOnly:=False, AppendDataOnExistingFile:=True
End Sub
```

I couldn't find any old question that can actually point me in right direction.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
Already tried FORMAT(CellValue,"yyyy-mm-dd") without success.

**Update 2:**
Also tried reading the cell value in a string variable and then converting it back into date type like this:

```
If IsDate(CellValue) Then
      Dim str1 As String
      str1 = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
      Dim DateValue As Date
      DateValue = CDate(str1)
      CellValue = Format(DateValue, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End If
```

No use,  in fact, it seems that code to is not executing (no compile error though).

**Update 3:**
Finally,  I'm able to solve it using `.NumberFormat` and `.Text`. See my answer below for final code and the limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally, i'm able to solve the problem using `NumberFormat` and `.Text`.  Thanks to @Ed Heywood-Lonsdale for his patience with me,  though it wasn't much helpful.  Now my code looks like this:

```
Public Sub ExportToCsvFile(FName As String, _
    Sep As String, SelectionOnly As Boolean, _
    AppendDataOnExistingFile As Boolean)

Dim WholeLine As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstCol As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
FNum = FreeFile

If SelectionOnly = True Then
    With Selection
        FirstRow = .Cells(1).Row
        FirstCol = .Cells(1).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
Else
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        FirstRow = .Cells(1).Row
        FirstCol = .Cells(1).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
End If

If AppendDataOnExistingFile = True Then
    Open FName For Append Access Write As #FNum
Else
    Open FName For Output Access Write As #FNum
End If

For RowNdx = FirstRow To LastRow
    WholeLine = ""
    For ColNdx = FirstCol To LastCol

        If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
            CellValue = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
        Else
           CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
            If IsDate(CellValue) Then
                Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Text
            End If
           CellValue = Replace(Replace(CellValue, Chr(150), Chr(45)), Chr(151), Chr(45))
           CellValue = Replace(Replace(CellValue, Chr(60), Chr(60) & Chr(32)), Chr(10), "<br />")
           CellValue = Chr(34) & Replace(CellValue, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)
        End If

        WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
    Next ColNdx
    WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))
    Print #FNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #FNum

End Sub

Sub ExportToSemiColonCsv()
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim Sep As String
    FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=vbNullString, FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")
    If FileName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ExportToCsvFile FName:=CStr(FileName), Sep:=";", _
       SelectionOnly:=False, AppendDataOnExistingFile:=True
End Sub
```

There is still one problem with this macro,  it is unable to handle dates pre-1900,  the lame intentional bug of excel.  I'll probably find a way to do this within the macro as VBA supports negative datevalues, so, dates between 0100-1900 are also supported.

Hope my macro above helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like...

```
Next RowNdx

for i = 0 to 25
    column = chr(64 + i)
    header = Range(column & "1")
    if header = "Application Data" then
        columns(column).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
        msgbox "Column " & column & "Has been formatted"
    end if
next

EndMacro:
```

If you want to search into columns AA and beyond, you need a second loop and to concatenate the strings. (eg column = chr(64+i) & chr(64+j))

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  After adding your code,  the saved CSV/text file is blank. Can you please show implementation of your solution inside my VBA?

Comment: Yep, I've put the rows either side of it. Have also added a little pop up so that you know what is being formatted

Comment: Still won't work.  Now the output file has data but the date format is still same.  For example,  in excel file, i had 12/06/2003, it's coming out same in the output as 12/06/2003 instead of 2003-06-12

Comment: OK. Looking at the data, has the format been changed? If yes, it's a question of changing it too late (after the export has already happened... I'm not familiar with exporting like that so can't follow your code) but if not, then my code isn't working, probably by not picking up the right columns to change